# Cout in loop doesn't print char by char as defined

Tags: c++, string, delay, cout

I've recently started learning C++ at university and decided to advance a bit at home. I had the idea of making a program that, given a piece of text, would print out such text character by character with a small delay in-between (as seen in this video [SUPER.HOT chat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vM8gw1M2llc)).

I tried to recreate it using a simple procedure:

```
void typer(string text){

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
    cout << text[i];
    usleep(100000);
}
```

But when usleep() is set under 103900, it'll start printing out two characters at a time. My intention is to print only 1 at a time but very quickly.

Any suggestions? :D

Comment: What happens if you use `sleep(1)` rather than `usleep(100000)`? Does it actually work with `usleep(103900)` and fail with `usleep(103899)`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush the stream, otherwise it will be cached

```
cout.flush();
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/basic_ostream/flush/

Comment: Tried both ways (cout.flush(); and cout << text[i] << flush;) before and after usleep(), still nothing.

Comment: @Alex: It works for me with either `std::cout.flush()` or `std::cout << text[i] << std::flush`.

Comment: @Alex try `nanosleep()`instand of `usleep()`; usleep is obsolet, ... may it helps

Answer (score 1):

You need flush output

```
 cout << text[i] << flush;
```

[The `usleep()` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) returns `0` on success.  On error, `-1` is returned, with errno set to indicate the cause of the error.

ERRORS 
`EINTR`  Interrupted by a signal; see signal(7).

`EINVAL` usec is not smaller than `1000000`.  (On systems where that is considered an error.)

Comment: How is the return value of `usleep()` relevant? The code in the question just calls it and ignores both the result it returns and any `errno` value. It's unlikely to fail. But yes, on the off chance that `usleep()` might be failing for the OP, checking the return value would be a good debugging step (but I'd be surprised if that were the issue).

Comment: I think `usleep()` might fail to sleep.

Comment: Unlikely, but worth checking. (I updated my comment as you were typing yours.)